# Vue.js single file component doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new with Vue and Vue cli. I'd like to try out this [vue-tabs-component](https://github.com/spatie/vue-tabs-component). And my code in App.vue is as follows:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <tabs>
        <tab name="First tab">
            First tab content
        </tab>
        <tab name="Second tab">
            Second tab content
        </tab>
        <tab name="Third tab">
            Third tab content
        </tab>
    </tabs>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'vue-tabs-component';
Vue.component('tabs', Tabs);
Vue.component('tab', Tab);
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

In browser:
[screenshot of my demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI2hl.png), 
and the demo given by the author:
[screenshot of author's demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjHfy.png). As you can see, this component lost it's css.

What can I do to fix it, please show me the way!

Comment: There should be some CSS files associated with the tabs component. You need them in your app.

Comment: His demo includes http://vue-tabs-component.spatie.be/resources/tabs-component.css

Comment: Does it mean that when I use third-party components in the future， I have to add CSS on my own? which is  very troublesome.@RoyJ

Comment: You can hope that other third-party components will be better packaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS you need is currently available via:

```
import 'vue-tabs-component/docs/resources/tabs-component.css';
```

Example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'vue-tabs-component';
import 'vue-tabs-component/docs/resources/tabs-component.css';

Vue.component('tabs', Tabs);
Vue.component('tab', Tab);
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
```

It may work, but as it is not in the `dist` folder, it may be, I guess, removed in the future.

Comment: The author didn't mention this. Adding CSS by users, which make things complicated. The authors who provide components are supposed to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: I agree, but this is the only CSS file included in the dist. Do `npm i vue-tabs-component` and check the `node_modules/vue-tabs-component` folder.